# Django и SSL sslforfree.com

Tags: nginx, letsencrypt

Впервые пытаюсь использовать SSL сертификат в проекте Django.

Сертификат беру [тут](https://www.sslforfree.com/) (т.е., фактически, от [letsencrypt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt)).

Генерил сертификат без CSR.

В архифе пришло три файла: ca_bundle.crt, certificate.crt, private.key.

Nginx отдаёт 2 файла: certificate.crt и private.key.

Всё работает нормально, за исключением Android устройств, когда заходишь с любого Android браузера, выдаёт "ошибку" как при самоподписном сертификате.

***Дополнение***

[ssl-checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) возвращает, среди прочего, это:

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
>   install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
>   certificate.

Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать утилиту openssl, и что-то делать с файлом ca_bundle.crt, но не могу нарыть что именно.

Comment: А если просто заменить certificate.crt на ca_bundle.crt?

Comment: При nginx -t отдаёт nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/var/www/site/private.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)

Comment: Что именно не работает? Вангую, что в андроиде просто нет нужных корневых сертификатов.

Comment: Стандартная ошибка, как будто бы сертификат самоподписный.

Comment: Какой андроид? https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/

Comment: Версия Android 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

исходя из названия файла и приведённой вами информации, скорее всего, в файле `ca_bundle.crt` хранится [промежуточный (intermediate ca) сертификат](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/), которым и подписан ваш сертификат (присланный вам в файле certificate.crt).

из этих двух файлов вам надо сформировать один, состоящий из вашего сертификата (должен идти первым) и промежуточного. тогда **все** http-клиенты смогут проверить действительность вашего сертификата.

имя у этого файла может быть произвольным (частенько в нём упоминают имя домена и суффикс `.crt`, исключительно для удобства):

```
$ (cat certificate.crt; echo; cat ca_bundle.crt) > ваш.домен.crt
```

и в конфигурации *nginx* надо будет указать именно этот файл в качестве сертификата:

```
ssl_certificate /путь/к/файлу/ваш.домен.crt
```

---

> Nginx отдаёт 2 файла: certificate.crt и private.key.

что-то вы сделали неправильно. http-сервер не должен их просто так «отдавать». в файлах сертификатов, конечно, нет ничего секретного, а вот файл с секретным ключом `private.key` должен храниться «в секрете».

---

p.s. такая сложная команда со скобками и `echo` нужна для ситуации, когда первый файл не содержит в конце символа новой строки.

Comment: Я неверно выразился.
Под "отдаёт", я подразумевал следующее:
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certificate.crt;  # <-
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private.key;  # <-

Comment: Обязательно ли файл должен называться так же, как доменное имя?
Как быть, если домен кирилический? Называть файл в punycode, или же это рекомендация, а не обязательное условие?

Comment: я же написал — имя произвольное. хоть `bla.bla,bla!` его назовите. главное — именно это имя и укажите в конфигурации nginx.

Comment: Всё отлично работает. 
Большое спасибо!
Единственный нюанс, что после конкатенации nginx отдаст ошибку:
failed (SSL: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line), т.к. внутри нового файла склеится начало и конец 
  -----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----,
а нужно чтобы ----END и ----BEGIN должны быть на разных строках

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, я исправил команду, чтобы избежать подобной ситуации.